# Is there any cable with jack 6.3mm male to jack 3.5mm female?

Tags: cable

I'm trying to find an extension cable for my sound interface, which features a 6.3mm jack output for monitoring, since my headphones have a very short cable that is always stretched.

I already have an adapter from 6.3 to 3.5, but I was looking for a cable instead so I would not need to use a cable with the adapter I could only use one thing.

The issue is, on the internet I can't seem to find such cable. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords, or there's some technical limitation to that (which seems odd to me) or there's just not enough market for people wanting this things, which is also odd giving the number of adapters I find.

Do you guys know anything about this?

Comment: use a 3.5mm plug to 3.5mm socket extender cable, then use an adapter to 1/4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was looking for a cable instead... Do you guys know anything about
>   this?

Yes, here is an example: [Thomann: Cordial CFM 3 VY](https://www.thomann.de/ie/cordial_cfm_3_vy.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Also, as an 'fyi', you can knock any type of cable together with a simple understanding and a solder-iron. I've bought components from [Professional Audio Cables](https://procables.audio/) before and soldered them myself. They're still working now actually.

But if you're stuck and you haven't got a solder iron or the will, places like Professional Audio Cables and others will happily put a custom cable together for you.